# What is a non diagonal matrix?

Tags: matrices

Is it something like the diagonal elements are zeroes and the off diagonal elements may or may not be zeroes?

Comment: No, it just means a matrix that is not diagonal!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least one of the off-diagonal entries is non-zero. You don't have to check the diagonal entries.